# How to tag both the align and individual equations within it?

Tags: align, labels, tag

I was trying to create tags for both the optimization problem and individual constraints within it. Below is an example. Is this possible in LaTex?

```
  \begin{align}\tag{P1}
    \begin{split}
    \max_{x,y} & f(x,y) \\
    s.t.  & x+y \leq 5 \tag{constraint1} \\
    & x+2y \geq 10 \tag{constraint2}
    \end{split}
    \end{align}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another solution, with the `mini!` environment from the `optidef` package, which is dedicated to the formatting of optimisation problems:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[short]{optidef}

\begin{document}

    \begin{mini!}
        {(x, y)}{f(x, y) \tag{P1}\label{P1}}
        {}{}
        \addConstraint{x + y}{\leq 6\tag{constraint 1}}
        \addConstraint{x + 2y}{\geq 10\tag{constraint 2}}
   \end{mini!}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could try with this not elegant suggestion:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \max_{x,y} & \quad f(x,y) \tag{P1}\\
    s.t.  & \quad x+y \leq 5  \tag{constraint 1}\\
          & \quad x+2y \geq 10 \tag{constraint 2}
    \end{align}

\end{document}
```